# Display XP Style CFileDialog in Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I want to display `CFileDialog` like the image below in Windows 7.

[image: desired dialog]

As per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> if `OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE` is set and `OFN_EXPLORER` flag is not set, the system uses the template to create an old-style dialog box that replaces the default dialog box.

But even after doing that what I get is something like this.
[image: The one I get]

Please help!

Comment: link to msdn is malformed, why do you keep returning it to a text instead of link?

Comment: stackoverflow does not allow more than two hyperlinks! and they don't allow images to users reputation below 10. so i used hyperlinks for two images and i had to make the msdn link text. only the http:// portion is missing.

Comment: Why do you want the old windows xp style one instead of the windows 7 equivalent?

Comment: Because my client wants it like that :(

Comment: @rageshtech, yes, but I edited the post, then you edited it back.

Comment: @unkulunkulu Oops! sorry for that! I only meant to remove a sentence from first paragraph! but when i did it, i couldn't save because of the inline images, so I had to revert it  :(

Comment: :) Funny enough, I removed that sentence too in my edit :) ok, I sent an edit again, so it'll be ok in some time

Comment: You can provide the actual piece of code creating the dialog, people will be able to test it provide some suggestions. Although it could make you undo my changes again :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
CFileDialog fd(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,FALSE);
fd.m_ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME_NT4);
fd.DoModal();
```

The last parameter to CTOR specifies Vista-style to be false, and structure size of `sizeof`ed with to reflect NT4 file-dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. That windows belong to OS and is not implemented anymore. The the closest thing you can use is the old-style dialog box.

You can try to customize this one by hooking the window but it's not easy and I don't thing it worth.

Comment: Actually the first image is the one dialog that another applicaiton displays in Windows 7! I wanna know whether I can display CFileDialog from my application like that! Please check the two images.